# .Net Connector for MySQL - Parameter

Tags: mysql, .net, parameters

I have a datatable, containing two rows: id char(9), eh char(4). Both rows contains numeric values (I can't change this), for example 123456789.

The query
SELECT id,eh FROM tab WHERE id LIKE '123456789'
directly in the MySQL-client works fine, in VB.net too.

But if I use a parameter in VB.net instead of building the query-string, the query returns null rows. This is what I've done (not the complete code):

```
Dim com As New MySqlCommand
com.CommandText = "SELECT id,eh FROM tab WHERE id LIKE @i"
com.Parameters.Add("@i", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
com.Parameters("@i").Value = number
```

I think, the connector does not send the quotes of the string (maybe because there are only numbers), because if I change the first query in the MySQL-client to ... LIKE 123456789, I get null rows, too.

Do you have any hints or workarounds for me?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
MySqlDbType.String
```

As your parameter type.

*Note.. I do not use MySql but a quick google came up with char as a string.*

**EDIT**

Maybe you are missing the Apostrophes around you @i

```
com.CommandText = "SELECT id,eh FROM tab WHERE id LIKE '@i'"
```

Comment: Well, I tried String, Text, VarString, TinyText all with the same result.

Comment: If you do it like you edit it (LIKE '@i'), it will pass the string "@i" instead of the value.

Comment: Is 'number' a int or a string? maybe try casting before setting the parameter value?

Comment: number is a string. I choose this name to show, that the value contains only numbers.

Comment: Stumped then sorry. Everything looks right to me.
Maybe someone else are give you the advice you need.